# SpeechSynthesizer::SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync function takes forever

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, text-to-speech, c++-cx, speech-synthesis

I have the following C++/CX code:

```
Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::SpeechSynthesizer^ synth = ref new Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::SpeechSynthesizer();
Platform::String^ text = "This is a string of text.";
concurrency::create_task(synth->SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text))
  .then([&](Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::SpeechSynthesisStream^ stream) {
      mediaElement->AutoPlay = true;
      mediaElement->SetSource(stream, stream->ContentType);
      mediaElement->Play();
  });
```

If my understanding is correct, it is supposed to synthesize the string `This is a string of text.` into a stream that would then be played through a `MediaElement`. After I execute this code, however, the lambda specified in `task.then()` never runs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me. A few possibilities:

1. You don't have the `Microphone` capability and you are swallowing an `Access Denied` exception(*)
2. Calling `Play` is throwing and you are swallowing the exception(**)
3. You are running on a device that doesn't have a default speech language installed (`DefaultVoice == nullptr`)

(*) Although you're not actually using the Microphone for speech synthesis, the way the speech system works in Windows Phone you need this capability

(**) You should never call `Play` immediately after setting the `Source`; you must wait for the `MediaOpened` event to be raised (or, in this case, rely on `AutoPlay` to do the work for you).

Comment: I do have the `Microphone` capability declared in my `.appxmanifest`. I tried manually setting a voice from the `AllVoices` list and putting all the code in a try/catch block and no exceptions were thrown. The problem isn't with the `MediaElement` itself - just with the `SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync()` method. As I said, it runs forever and never runs the lambda specified in `task.then()`.

Comment: I hit this issue once actually and had to reboot the device / emulator to fix it. Basically the Synthesize call worked once but then never again. Try restarting and make sure you close the SpeechSynthesizer object when it is done

Comment: Thanks for your help.